# extract part of description, to show in title

Tags: php

I have the following code in the page title, on 1500 pages all the same

```
$title = "Detail --Homes For Sale";
```

and would like to extract the first 80 characters from the description into the title, so that each page has a unique title.

the description code is like below,

```
<?=nl2br(stripslashes(substr($emlaklist->aciklama,0,200)))?>
```

any suggestions how this can work?

Comment: `substr($string, 80);` ?

Comment: substr($string,0,80);

Comment: so would this be your example $title = "substr($string, 80);";

Comment: @antalya yes but $string is equal to the variable holding your description. See my answer below

Comment: @antalya please review my answer

Comment: @antalya can you review my answer please? It has been an hour and have had no feedback from you

Comment: @AndyHolmes i think our dev just fled the crime scene without marking an accepted answer :(

Comment: @Ayub - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24861785/extract-10-words-from-product-description-into-the-page-title if you're interested where OP went...

Comment: @Hecksa why OP do this? plenty of good answers here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also have to make sure, that your variable (`$emlaklist`) is already set, where you want to append it's value to the `$title` variable.

In general you might try to copy the code-part that starts with `$emlaklist = ..` to the place before your `$title =`, but most likely this will be a database request, so you might need to take other code into account, that contributes to getting that value ...

Other than that, the other answers here will be very well able to handle the shortening of your description, etc.

(Sry that this is too long for a comment, but it might be helpful anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to utilise `substr()` function for your title.

You would do it like `substr($string, 0, 80);` where `$string` is the variable that holds the description, `0` is the start of the string and `80` is where the string you want ends.

Here is what I think you're after based on your question

```
$description = stripslashes(substr($emlaklist->aciklama,0,200));

$title = substr($descripton, 0, 80);
```

Comment: As question was unclear this could well be correct answer - so +1 from me!

Answer (score 1):

```
$title = "Detail --Homes For Sale";

$description = stripslashes(substr($emlaklist->aciklama,0,80));

$title = $title . " " . $description;
```

Comment: these are good answers but i am no expert. could you please provide how i would need to write this $title = "Detail --Homes For Sale";

Comment: What are you actually wanting to achieve - from what you have written it looks like every page has the title 'Detail --Homes For Sale' - this is stored in a variable and echoed out into the page. The answer I gave assumes you want to keep the first part and append the first 80 characters from the description to the end to give 'Detail --Homes For Sale First 80 characters from description...' is this not what you want?

Comment: here is the page, i would like the title to extract 80 characters of the description to make the page titles unique http://www.turkish-property-world.com/detail.php?KKId=2965&Ino=3

Comment: for example i would like to have the titles show as so $title="LUXURY SEAVIEW VILLA for sale in Tepe Alanya"

Comment: Then you just need to set `$title = stripslashes(substr($emlaklist->aciklama,0,80));` then inside the title tags just do `<?php echo $title; ?>`

Comment: could you please explain more details for above exmple i think we are close. must not stripslashes(substr($emlaklist->aciklama,0,80)); be within quotes to function, otherwise it just shows as written.